# Get ec2 instance metadata from instance id

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, automation, boto

Hi I am using boto to spin up ec2 spot instance. I am having trouble getting instance hostname from instance id.

there is easies way to do from instance itself "wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id"

but I am looking for way to get metadata using instance id

Any Help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance metadata is only available on the instance but you can get a lot of information about your instance using the EC2 API.  So, if you have the instance ID you can do this:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')  # or whatever region you use
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids='i-12345678')
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
print(instance.public_dns_name)
```

Would print the public DNS name (i.e. hostname) of the instance.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I got following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get_all_instances() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance_id'

Comment: Sorry, the parameter is ``instance_ids``.  It can be a list of ids or just a single value.  I corrected the example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname"`

to get EC2 instance hostname